# Tic-Tac-Toe minimax AI not working beyond end game. Recursion issues, where are they?

Tags: javascript, recursion, artificial-intelligence, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I managed to get a very simple AI for my tic tac toe working, but only for the last move, when it's an obvious choice between two -- I can have the algorithm put a marker in one remaining space, see if there's a winner, and if not, clear the board, put it in the other space, and see if there's a winner, and return the right choice.

However, when I try to do the recursion, something's not working right. Can you take a look and tell me where it's falling apart? I rubber-ducked my way through, and it seems right to me. It's also very slow, so I must be screwing up somewhere.

```
function bestAIMove() {
  var smartAIArray = listEmptySpaces();
  let bestScore = -100000
  var move;
  for (var i = 0; i < smartAIArray.length; i++) {
    let smartAIpicked = smartAIArray[i];
    origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.add(TWO_CLASS);
    origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = TWO_CLASS;
      let score = minimax(origBoard)
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.remove(TWO_CLASS);
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = "";
  if (score > bestScore) {
    bestScore = score;
    move = smartAIpicked;
    console.log(move)
  } 
}
origBoard[move].classList.add(TWO_CLASS);
origBoard[move].innerHTML = TWO_CLASS;
}





function minimax() {
  if (playerhasWon() &&  playerOneTurn) {
    return -10;
  } else if (playerhasWon() && !playerOneTurn) {
    return 10;
  } else if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
    return 0;
  }
  swapTurns()

// the recursive part from here down is the problem

  if (!playerOneTurn) {
    let bestScore = -100000; 
    var smartAIArray = listEmptySpaces();
    for (var i = 0; i < smartAIArray.length; i++) {
      let smartAIpicked = smartAIArray[i];
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.add(TWO_CLASS);
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = TWO_CLASS;
        let score = minimax(origBoard)
        origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.remove(TWO_CLASS);
        origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = "";
        if (score > bestScore) {
          bestScore = score}
      }
    return bestScore;
    }
   else {


    let bestScore = 100000; 
    var smartAIArray = listEmptySpaces();
    for (var i = 0; i < smartAIArray.length; i++) {
      let smartAIpicked = smartAIArray[i];
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.add(ONE_CLASS);
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = ONE_CLASS;
        let score = minimax(origBoard)
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].classList.remove(ONE_CLASS);
      origBoard[smartAIpicked].innerHTML = "";
      if (score < bestScore) {
        bestScore = score}
      }
    return bestScore;
  }
}
```

If I just limit the code to `bestAIMove` and the `if` statement that evaluates the scores in `minimax()`, it behaves. Everything after is a nightmare though, even though it it's basically a nested version of the code in `bestAIMove()`

- In `bestAIMove()` loop through the empty spaces known as `smartAIArray`;
- Change `origBoard` to put a marker in [i] space;
- Evaluate the score via `minimax()`;
- If there is no score, run `swapTurns()`, then turn to `else` part of `minimax`;
- Turn to listEmptySpaces() again. Run another for loop. Put a marker in [i] space again.
- Evaluate the score via `minimax()` again;
- If there is no score, run `swapTurns()`;
- Then start on `if (!playerOneTurn)` part of `minimax`;
- Repeat until you get a score;
- That score is placed in bestAIMove;
- the marker used to test the spot is removed;
- The next empty space will be evaluated;
- The empty space that gets the highest score is where the marker will go
- The corresponding space will be called `move` and represent where the AI moves

What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: I have it in repl.it here if you're curious to see it work at the endgame. Just set up your board by filling in six places as a human-vs-human game and then confirm you want a "Smart AI" game: https://repl.it/@acchang/TicTacToe-Anew#script.js [X,(),O, X, X,(), O,(),O] is a good test configuration with three spaces left. If you change to "Smart AI" and put an X in the bottom row, it should be smart enough to chose the middle row, not the top one.

Comment: You're mixing concerns here.  If every single test move is going to change the DOM, it's going to cause you all sorts of problems.  Try to create a data structure to represent your board -- a simple array of 'X's, 'O's. or digits could be all you need -- and then do your testing against that.

Comment: ok! I just instituted a `var newBoard = [...origBoard];` so I can test against `newBoard` runs a lot smoother, even if the logic isn't quite there yet. I'm reluctant to use a simple array of Xs and Os because my check for winner, check for tie and check for empty space functions are all based on class and inner html

Answer (score 1):

## Overview

I was interested in this.  One of my very first programming experiences was writing tic-tac-toe in old line-number BASIC on a TRS-80.  (Yes, I'm that old!)  I don't think I've tried to write one in the forty years since.  Modern languages with features like recursion, first-class functions, and so on make this an easier project than it was for the 13-year-old me.

Below is an attempt to write a reasonable minimax function for a simple board expressed, for instance, as `['1', 'X', '3', '4', '5', 'O', '7', '8', '9']`and a player expressed as `'X'` or `'O'`.  The idea is that this model can easily be used as the underpinnings for whatever user interface you choose to display and interact with the game.

## Design

We use a number of small -- even tiny -- single-purpose functions operating on simple datatypes.  All out data is immutable.  None of it is global.  We simply pass the necessary items to each function, and return results rather than modifying global objects. This code does not address a user interface at all.  A full system would layer that atop the functions here.

## Code

```js
const randomChoice = (xs) =>
  xs [Math .floor (Math .random () * xs .length)]

const move = (player, square, board) => 
  board .map (x => x === square ? player : x)

const availableMoves = (board) => 
  board .filter (x => /\d/ .test (x))

const checkWin = ((wins) => (player, board) =>
  wins .some (squares => squares .every (square => board [square - 1] == player))
) ([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [1, 5, 9], [3, 5, 7]])

const score = (board) =>
  checkWin ('X', board) ? 10 : checkWin ('O', board) ? -10 : 0

const flipPlayer = (player) =>
  player == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'

const compare = (test) => (best, {move, score}) =>
  test (score, best [0] .score) 
    ? [{move, score}] 
  : score == best [0] .score 
    ? [...best, {move, score}] 
    : best

const bestMoves = (player, options) => 
  options .reduce (
    compare (player === 'X' ? (a, b) => a > b : (a, b) => a < b),
    [{move: null, score: player == 'X' ? -Infinity : Infinity}]
  )

const chooseBest = (player, options) => 
  randomChoice (bestMoves (player, options))

const minimax = (player, board, avail = availableMoves (board), val = score(board)) =>
  avail .length === 0 || val !== 0
    ? {move: null, score: val}
    : chooseBest (
        player,
        avail .map (square => ({
          move: square, 
          score: minimax (flipPlayer (player), move (player, square, board)) .score
        }))
      )

const parseBoard = (str) => 
  str .split ('\n') .filter (Boolean) .map (s=> s .trim ()) .flatMap (x => x .split (' '))

const results = minimax ('X', parseBoard (`
  1 X 3
  4 5 O
  7 8 9
`)) //=> randomly chooses between {move: 3, score: 10} and {move: 5, score: 10}

console .log (results)
```

### Utility functions

The first function is a general purpose utility function:

- **`randomChoice`** randomly chooses one element of an array.  We will use it below to make an AI player more interesting, choosing randomly from all moves that lead to the same result.

### Helper functions

The next few functions are general-purpose tic-tac-toe functions that are needed both to write a minimax function and also likely for game-play.  There is no error-checking in any of them.  That would still need to be layered on.

- **`move`** makes the given move for the current player on the board, returning an entirely new board.  This is important for the design.  We never mutate our input, only create new versions of it.

  For instance, if `board` looked like this:

  ```
    1 X 3
    4 5 O
    7 8 9
  ```

  Then `move('X', '7', board)` would return the new board

  ```
    1 X 3
    4 5 O
    X 8 9
  ```

  leaving the old board intact.
- **`availableMoves`** simply finds the digit squares in the board representation.  After the previous move above, `availableMoves (board)` would return `['1', '3', '4', '5', '8', '9']`
- **`checkWin`** accepts a player and a board and reports whether that player has already won.  It does this by simply testing against the eight possible wins on a tic-tac-toe board (three horizontal, three vertical and two diagonal.)
- **`score`** returns a score for the game, using your `+10` for 'X', `-10` for `O`, and `0` otherwise.  We check `X` first, and if someone had created a board that had wins for both players on it, this would yield a win for `X`.
- **`flipPlayer`** simply returns `'O'` when given `'X'` and vice-versa.

### Testing functions

The final function is

- **`parseBoard`**, which is simply used in testing to make it easier to see the board structure.  It converts a laid-out string into our array model.  That is, it turns

  ```
    1 X 3
    4 5 O
    7 8 9
  ```

  into `['1', '3', 'X', '4', '5', 'O', '7', '8', '9']`

The remainder of the functions are specifically used to build `minimax`, but before we discuss them, here are two functions we might want to have handy for developing and testing the rest of the system.  They are not needed in the above:

```js
const display = (board) => [
  board .slice (0, 3) .join (' '),
  board .slice (3, 6) .join (' '),
  board .slice (6, 9) .join (' ')
] .join ('\n')

const emptyBoard = () =>
  '123456789' .split ('')
```

- **`display`** turns a board into a reasonable output, reversing what `parseBoard` does.  That is, `display (['1', '3', 'X', '4', '5', 'O', 'X', '8', '9']` would yield

  ```
    1 X 3
    4 5 O
    X 8 9
  ```
- **`emptyBoard`** simply yields a blank board which can be used for starting a game.

### Central functions

Central to this is **`minimax`**, which accepts a player and a board and returns a `{move, score}` object representing the chosen move and the score it will achieve with best choices by each player.  If first finds the current score on the board and the list of available moves.  If there are no moves, or if there is already a win on the board, it simply returns a `null` move and that current score.  Otherwise, it finds the available moves and for each calculates the minimax results for the opposing player after the current player moves to that square.  From those with the best score, it randomly selects one and returns it.  This last is handled by **`chooseBest`**, which is a small wrapper around **`bestMoves`**, just calling `bestMoves` to find the top moves and `randomChoices` to select one.

**`bestMoves`** is probably the most complex block in here.  It is a fold (`.reduce(...)`) on the list of moves, using a reducing function that is generated by **`compare`** and an initial value that has a `null` move and a positive or negative infinite score, depending upon player.  The test function we pass to compare is also based on which player we're checking.  `compare` checks whether each candidate value is better than, equal to or worse than our current list of values, and returns respectively, a list holding just the candidate, the current list with the candidate added, or simply the current list.

If it's not clear what's going on, this is a refactoring -- to remove duplication -- of my original version of `bestMoves`, which had the `compare` equivalent inlined.  It looked like this:

```js
const bestMoves = (player, options) => 
  options .reduce (
    (best, {move, score}) => 
      player == 'X' 
        ? (score > best [0] .score ? [{move, score}] : score == best [0] .score ? [...best, {move, score}] : best)
        : (score < best [0] .score ? [{move, score}] : score == best [0] .score ? [...best, {move, score}] : best), 
    [{move: null, score: player == 'X' ? -Infinity : Infinity}]
  )
```

## Performance

In your version, you found that it wouldn't perform well on an empty board.  Almost certainly that's due to the DOM manipulations involved.  If you were changing the HTML board on every test, that would certainly slow things down.

Here, we're only manipulating arrays of single-character strings.  This will solve for the empty board in 600 - 800 ms in my tests on a mid-level laptop.  The example above, with two squares already filled in takes less than a tenth of a second.  (Usually 60 - 70 ms.)

## Lessons

1. Breaking a problem down into smaller parts makes code much simpler to understand.  It's easier to test as you go, and it makes it much easier to isolate problems.  Note that in solving the `minimax` problem here, I used ten custom functions, only one of them `randomChoice`, which is good for anything outside our tic-tac-toe system.  But `move`, `availableMoves`, `checkWin`, `score`, and `flipPlayer` all might be used elsewhere in the codebase.

   Because each function does a small dedicated job, they are simple to test.  But they don't really even add code.  The whole snippet is about the same size as your version of `minimax`.
2. Separating data models from how they are displayed makes code more robust.  Data models do not have to be complex.  Here we just used an array of nine single-character strings to represent the board and either `'X'` or `'O'` to represent the player.  Our most complex model item is the result from calls to `minimax`, and object with a `move` property drawn from the board and a numeric `score` property.  In using models like this, we can easily write simple functions to manipulate them.  Writing a user interface atop this would be straightforward.
3. There is much to be said for immutable data.  With no need to keep track of mutations we've made and undo them at the right time, it's much simpler to understand the state of our system.  Even our recursive call should be clear enough.
4. Using built-in array methods makes for more declarative code.  `for`-loops are almost never necessary, and in code like this, with all functions side-effect free, they would be just a distraction.  Note that we use **`.map`** in `move` and `minimax`, **`.filter`** in `availableMoves`, **`.some`** and **`.every`** in `checkWin`, **`.reduce`** in `bestMoves`, and that in `parseBoard` we use three such methods, **`.filter`**, **`.map`**, and **`.flatMap`**.  In every case, these could be rewritten with `for`-loops.  But in every case, that would bloat the code and make it *harder* to understand.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to explain this to me. I definitely have not absorbed it all (still re-reading for the n-th time) but small parts are slowly sinking in. I refactored my board again, per your suggestion to simplify to primitives and it's a lot smoother. The logic still has problems (I think my recursion is only taking first order results into effect) but I've taken yet another tiny step towards my end goal! https://repl.it/@acchang/TicTacToe-Anew#script.js

Comment: I got it to work! Doing it with primitives and breaking everything down was very good advice: https://tictactoe-anew.acchang.repl.co/ But testing 8! boards may still have been too much, so I made the first move random. Makes it a little more interesting too, imo. Do you have any suggestions for making it run faster? I'd still like to keep the interface. Would removing all the `console.log` help?

Comment: I'm very glad to hear you got it working.  I'm afraid your link does not work for me, neither in Brave nor in Chrome.  I'm not sure what's wrong.  No board ever shows, though.  Without working code, I probably can't comment on the approach.  Let me know if there's some other way I can see it working.  (Cutting and pasting into CodePen didn't help.)  I might take a go at a full tic-tac-toe system over the weekend, too.  If I do, I'll share here my approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response -- here is an alternative, though because it comes off github, it's even slower to load! Please let me know if this does not work either https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/acchang/TicTacToeAnew/blob/main/index.html

Comment: @acchang: Well it's working for me now, and you're right, it's amazingly slow to load.  I haven't looked at the code.  Perhaps I'll try after work.